# neo4j cypher, return fields instead of nodes when collecting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following query

```
match (a)-->(b)-->(c)
where id(a) = 0
return b.name, collect(c) as cs
```

How it's possible to return a collection composed of only a couple of fields, instead of the whole nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match (a)-->(b)-->(c)
where id(a) = 0
return b.name, collect( { field1: c.field1, field2: c.field2 } ) as cs
```

Answer (score 0):

A single field is easy:

```
match (a)-->(b)-->(c)
where id(a) = 0
return b.name, collect(c.fieldName) as cs
```

For multiple field names, maybe concatenate them?

```
match (a)-->(b)-->(c)
where id(a) = 0
return b.name, collect(c.fieldName1 + delimiter + c.fieldName2) as cs
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the former question. (also as fields can be big arrays and maps this feels just like plain bad code.)

Comment: Your question asks about returning a collection of fields instead of nodes- maybe edit the question with more details?

Comment: The question is very clear. Your answer simply doesn't provide a solution, just a workaround.

Comment: How it's possible to return a collection composed of only a couple of fields, instead of the whole nodes? Single field: see above, multiple fields--either return them separately as collects which will in turn group them, or concatenate them, or return the entire node and pick the fields you want in your code. Those are your options as far as I'm aware.